# Improve MDX query performance

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a query that is taking way too long to run.

I have a cube which has the measures [Days Open] and [Days Overdue]. Any query which filters on these measures is what causes the problem. This is the start of the MDX:

```
WITH  
SET [Measure Filter] 
  AS FILTER( 
       [Event Work Order].[Event Work Order ID].Members, 
     ( ([Measures].[Days Open] >= 1 AND [Measures].[Days Open] <= 250 )  )) 
Member [Measures].[Work Order Measure] AS 
     (SUM([Measure Filter]
        , [Measures].[Work Order Count] ))
```

The underlying data that the measures a created from has a column for each of these values in the record. Can I create a dimension for days overdue and days open that can then be filtered on? If I do will it speed up the execution of the query?

Comment: Well the function FILTER is slow as it is iterative and likely not calculating in block mode so your idea to change the underlying structure is probably worth trying

Answer (score 0):

Only changes I’d make would be an intermediate step of consolidating the SET and then just using a tuple for the final measure but I think the following are just essentially syntactic changes that won’t help with performance

```
WITH  
SET [OrderID set]
  AS FILTER( 
       [Event Work Order].[Event Work Order ID].Members, 
       [Measures].[Days Open] >= 1 
             AND [Measures].[Days Open] <= 250 
       )
MEMBER [Event Work Order].[Event Work Order ID].[All].[OrderID set sum] AS
  SUM([OrderID set])
Member [Measures].[Work Order Measure] AS 
     ([Event Work Order].[Event Work Order ID].[All].[OrderID set sum] 
        , [Measures].[Work Order Count] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying NonEmpty function around the Event Work order dimension and Days open Measure.

Could you also simplfy filter to be just <= and remove the AND.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Dimension called [Work Order Days Open] which contained all the unique days open values.

The original query was:

```
WITH  SET [Measure Filter] AS (FILTER( [Event Work Order].[Event Work Order ID].Members, ( ([Measures].[Days Open] >= 10 AND [Measures].[Days Open] <= 250 )  ))) Member [Measures].[Work Order Measure] AS (SUM([Measure Filter], [Measures].[Work Order Count] )) SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Work Order Measure]  } ON 0, NON EMPTY { (  EXCEPT( [Category Type].[Category Type Name].Members  , [Category Type].[Category Type Name].[All] )   ) } ON 1 FROM [Work Order] WHERE ( {  [Event Start Dates].[Date Key].[20160724] :  [Event Start Dates].[Date Key].[20180124]   })
```

This had an execution time of **2:31**

With the new Dimension the new query is:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Work Order Count] } ON 0, 
NON EMPTY { ( EXCEPT( [Category Type].[Category Type Name].Members , [Category Type].[Category Type Name].[All] ) ) } ON 1 
FROM [Work Order] 
WHERE ( { [Event Start Dates].[Date Key].[20160724] : [Event Start Dates].[Date Key].[20180124] }, 
 {[Work Order Days Open].[Days Open].[10] : [Work Order Days Open].[Days Open].[250] } )
```

This has an execution time of **0:04**

As you can see the introduction of the new dimension had a **dramatic** impact on the query performance.